# Add an attribute to product where NAME contains "something"

Tags: attributes

I nedd to add a specific attribute to products where product name contains "sometingh".
Example:
Product Name: "shoes ARMANI leather patent"
Attribute Designer: empty
I would add ARMANI to attribue DESIGNER for all products that have on NAME the word "ARMANI".

Answer (score 1):

Yon can do that using an external magento script,

1) load a collection of product having "something" in name
2) loop through the collection, set the attribute, save the product

```
    include 'app/Mage.php';
    Mage::app();

    $collection = Mage::getModel('catalog/product')->getCollection();
    $collection->addAttributeToSelect('name');
    $collection->addAttributeToSelect('designer');
    $collection->addAttributeToFilter('name', array('like' => '%ARMANI%'));

    foreach ($collection as $product)

{
     echo 'product ' . $product->getSku();

            $product->setData('designer','Armani');
            $product->save();
        }        
}
```

a quicker vai to save only one attribute of a product is to replace the

```
$product->save();
```

with

```
$product->getResource()->saveAttribute($product, 'designer');
```

hope this helps